# Read from file and display in GUI java

Tags: java, parameter-passing

I need to read the file in the main than add the red lines (from the file) to an array in the class that stores array objects and display in GUI class. My problem is that nothing goes to the GUI. The `getTeamName` from `Team` returns `null`.

I read the file in

```
                fr = new FileReader("TeamsIn.txt"); 
                Scanner in = new Scanner(fr);
                while (in.hasNextLine()){
                String line = in.nextLine();

                team = new Team(line);
                team = teamIn.addTeam(team);
```

than I add lines to the Team [] array in MatchManager

```
    public  Team addTeam( Team teamName)
    {
         for(int i = 0; i < MAX_TEAMS; i++)

                 teams[i] = teamName;

         return teamName;


    }
```

And i want to display in the GUI

```
         Team t = new Team(teamName);


     display = new JTextArea(ROWS, COLUMNS);
     display.setEditable(false);
     display.setText(t.getTeamName());
     JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(display);
     return scrollPane;




   public class Team {


    public Team(String teamName){
        this.teamName = teamName;
        //System.err.println(teamName);
    }




    public String getTeamName(){
        return teamName;
    }
    public String setTeamName(String tName){
        return teamName;
    }
```

But the `display.setText(t.getTeamName());` doesnt return anything.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The question you're asking is really broad and you've posted a lot of code that makes it hard for us to understand where the problem might be hiding. Could you please try to reduce it down to a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/)? Also, please let us know what you've tried.

Comment: I believe "JavaBallTournamentGUI display" is some kind of a UI thingy like a JFrame. The problem is that you're not invoking any other function on "display" other than setVisible(..)

Comment: _"getTeamName from Team returns null"_ Where exactly do you call `getTeamName`?

Comment: And do you realize that in your `addTeam()` method, you're making every team in the array the same?

Comment: In the GUI display i have the JScrollPane and display.setText(t.getTeamName()); but the getTeamName(from Team class) returns nothing I can manually write in Team class getTeamName(){return "string"} than it write "string" in the GUI but not what is in the input file

Comment: @peeskillet I dont understand. when I print the array it returns me all the names of the teams

Comment: Why are you looping in addTeam() ?

Comment: @Scooter to add teams I red from the file in to Team[] array

Comment: @Pinoquio Typically in this situation your class would contain a count of the current number of teams and you would add to the slot based on this, incrementing the count each time. Or less preferably, you would null the array and loop until you found the first non-null slot and stick the new team there. You are doing neither - you add the new team to every slot in the array.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a bit of advice. You may want to restructure your entire program. I know it may seem like "*are you for real?"*, but yes I'm serious. I know you've probably spent a lot of time on it and the last thing you want to do is start over, but the reality of it is, you seem to have a really poor design. Here are some pointer.

- Keep the data and view separate. And have some structure to your data. What I mean by that is to keep all the data and data manipulation method in one class.

Here's an example, using ideas from your program

```
public class MatchManager {          // This class holds all the teams

    private List<Team> teams = new ArrayList<Team>();
    private int countTeam;
    private static  int MAX_TEAMS=8;

    public MatchManager(){
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("TeamsIn.txt"); 
            Scanner in = new Scanner(fr);

            while (in.hasNextLine()){
                String line = in.nextLine();

                Team team = new Team(line);
                teams.add(team);
            }
        } catch ( ... ) {}
    }

    public List<Team> getTeams(){
        return teams;
    }
}
```

What the above code does is Once you instantiate the `MatchManager`, all the teams will get populated.

---

- The `JavaBallTournamentGUI` class is the one that the program should be launched from. Remember how I talked about keeping the data and view separate. If you think about it, is data supposed to run? No, data is not a program. The GUI is a program though. So run the GUI program getting data from your *Model* class, the `MatchManager`.

Something like this.

```
public class JavaBallTournamentGUI extends JFrame {
    MatchManager manager = new MatchManager();
    List<Team> teams;

    public JavaBallTournamentGUI(){
        teams = manager.getTeams();
    }
}
```

Now you can use all the data from the `MatchManager` in the GUI class.

---

- I notice you instantiating the `Team` class in a couple different places. That really isn't necessary. Whenever you want to get the data of a team, you can just call it from the list of Teams,

like this

```
String oneTeam = teams.get(2).getTeamName();
textField.setText(oneTeam);
```

Do you notice how everything flows more smoothly this way? If you don't, sorry, I tried the best I could to explain. But I hope you get the main points of this. This type of design is much cleaner.

**Edit: To print all**

If its a JTextArea

```
for (Team team : teams){
    textArea.append(team.getTeamName() + "\n");
}
```

Comment: @peeskkillet thank you for help really appreciate it. I need to use simple arrays instead of array-list and need to read the file from the main method or in the GUI.

Comment: You can use an array, the same way I used the ArrayList. Just replace the list code with your original array code. And why do you need to read the file from the `main`. Once you create an instance of `MatchManager` in your GUI, all the date is store in the array. This is because of the `MatchManager` constructor. You want to have the `main` method in your GUI.

Comment: That's true I can read the file in MatchManager but I also  need the team class that holds team name and score. And the Team [] is an array of team objects

Comment: Does the file hold the score also or just the name? If the file holds the score also then have a constructor like `Team(String teamName, int score)` and create a `getScore()` to get the score of that team. So again you never have to create a new `Team` object. only when you create the array. The array will have the `Team` with the name and score.. Then just call the get methods to get them from the array.

Comment: Using the code you provided "String oneTeam = teams.get(2).getTeamName();" I finally get the team name at the second position printed in the GUI. What should I do to print all of them?